# maniuplating different items in ng-repeat dependant on index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to render information provided by a rails api.

I have 2 objects in my array, with different prices.

What I want to do is display to the user a price per hour, but dependant upon the price, I need to divide by a different number, meaning that depending upon the index of the item in the array. Currently, I am getting the total price, for each item, but wish to divide both items differently.

Currently the code I have is this:

**Javascript/Angular**

```
apiCall(function (data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    controller.holder.push({
    id: data[i].id,
    price: data[i].price  
  });
}

controller.holder = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 100
},{
   id: 1,
   price: 500
}]
```

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-repeat="pack in Test.holder" class="col-sm-6">
      <p>{{pack.hours}}  - {{pack.price | currency }}</p> 
      <button translate>Go</button> 
</div>
```

What I wish to achieve is something like this (please see comment in the code):

```
<div ng-repeat="pack in Test.holder" class="col-sm-6">
//if pack index in holder is 0 divide the item by 5
//if pack index in holder is 1 divide the item by 10 
          <p>{{pack.hours}}  - {{pack.price | currency }}</p> 
          <button translate>Go</button> 
</div>
```

By using $index is there a way to do this? After a lot of research I could not find a good answer for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any of the above is unclear and I can provide more details.

Comment: You can use `$index` to access the index inside the scope of the `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to divide the price by either 5 or 10:

```
<div ng-repeat="pack in Test.holder" class="col-sm-6">
   <p ng-if="$index == 0">{{pack.hours}}  - {{pack.price / 5 | currency }}</p> 
   <p ng-if="$index == 1">{{pack.hours}}  - {{pack.price / 10 | currency }}</p>
   <button translate>Go</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: If there might be more data in your *array* one day make sure to add a `<p>` tag like this: `<p ng-if="$index > 1">{{pack.hours}}  - {{pack.price | currency }}</p>`

Comment: With my code, for any elements with an `$index > 1` only the button will be displayed, which probably doesn't make too much sense. But you can use the same concept (`ng-if` and `$index`) on the button as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to use a combinaison of $index and the ng-if .

If index < 5 do this
else do that.

Comment: ok, perhaps I misunderstoof the solution. but index is either going to be 0 or 1, as there are only two items in the array

Comment: You're right, but the basic idea should work. Check my answer and tell me if that works for you!

Comment: Then i didn't understand the point of what you want. If you want to get access to your $index you just need to do ng-if="{{$index}} == 0" and it's done isn't it ?